# Is there a way to speed up this Objective-C string assignment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm doing a "stress test", I need to know how long it takes to do recursive operations in iPhone / iPad.

For example:

```
//"key" is defined in header.

for(int a=0;a<200;a++){
    for(int g=0;g<200;g++){

 key = @"hi";

    }
}
```

Do this value assignment (40.000 times) takes 6ms in iPad. But, if I do that:

```
for(int a=0;a<200;a++){
    for(int g=0;g<200;g++){

 key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i,%i",a,g]; 

    }
}
```

It takes almost 1 second!! For my application, I need to do this assignment more faster than this, someone knows another way to do?

Comment: Why don't you just write your app. I don't understand what performing loops 200 times and NSLogging a value is going to do. By the way, what is 'almost one second'?

Comment: Are you aware the second version of your code is creating 40000 NSString objects while the first is creating none (@"hi" is a constant NSString)? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can't make a comaprison between assigning a static value with assigning the result of an operation, surely there IS a difference of time.

Comment: 40000? Wow! That's crazy! If that takes less than a second, the thing is pretty darn fast.

Comment: Maybe rephrase the question as "Do recursive functions scale well in the iphone SDK? Is there a good way to test this?"

Comment: I just want to know what things make my app go slow in some processes. It's not part of the app, but I do something similar, more complex than a "for" of course. Thank you all.

Comment: Also, this isn't recursive, it's a simple iterative generation and assignment of NSStrings.  I don't understand how this is helping you to test recursion at all.

Comment: @HispaJavi - Rather than set up arbitrary tests, to understand what's slowing down your application you should perform profiling on your application when running on the device.  This is the only way to know for sure where your performance bottlenecks are.  Use the new Time Profiler instrument and its data mining capabilities to identify where the hotspots are within your application, and focus on those instead.  Making assumptions may come back to haunt you later on.

Comment: Mmm... microbenchmarks.   Awful lot of rope in something called "micro".   A compiler with full link knowledge would optimize that first loop away entirely (neither gcc nor llvm can do that because compilation is in isolation from linkage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int a=0;a<200;a++){
    for(int g=0;g<200;g++){
        char str[10];
        snprintf(str, 10, "%d,%d", a,g);
        key = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
}
```

Runs 4 times as fast on my old ipod touch 2g

Time old: 4.303022833333
Time new: 1.117406833333

Comment: Maybe it could even be made faster when using CFString, = less objc_msgSend

Comment: wow! My example in iPad takes 0,9 secs, your example takes 0,3!! Thanks you mate ;)

Comment: Note that you've also lost unicode support & localization support by going this route.  That may be just fine... but maybe not.   Note also that this could be made significantly faster by moving away from snprintf -- away from format parsing -- entirely.